# Weibo iOS SDK Bitcode error when archiving with Xcode7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode, weibo, sinaweibo

***Environment***

- Xcode 7.1
- OS X 10.11.1
- Archiving iOS with minimum target requirement 8.0

***Podfile***

pod "WeiboSDK", :head

***Error Message***

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/XX/code/iOS/Pods/WeiboSDK/libWeiboSDK/libWeiboSDK.a(WBSDKNormalWebViewController.o)'
>   was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for
>   bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for
>   architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

It's OK when building, but will fail when archiving

Answer (score 1):

download latest version of WeiboSDK. It supported bitcode

[weibo_ios_sdk](https://github.com/sinaweibosdk/weibo_ios_sdk)

Answer (score 0):

> 1.If your app doesn't need bitcode (for Apple Watch).you should check you settings:

```
PROJECT/TARGETS -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode -> NO
```

> 2.If you need the Bitcode enable in your project,you should import the newest SDK from Weibo which has been build by Bitcode enabled.

***The problem you have met is that if you want to enable your Bitcode in your project,the library in your project must be build by "Enable Bitcode".***

About Bitcode,the official documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2

The "Bitcode" is one of the adaption details of iOS 9.0 or above.You should pay attention to this.Here is a good repository on Github for iOS 9 adaption details collection:
https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS9AdaptationTips